# Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatable to display results in the same search page, kindly rectify my mistake it shows "Cannot reinitialise Data table".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#reportsSearch").submit(function(e){
         $("#displayInfo").hide();
         alert("asdasd");
        var csrf = document.getElementById("csrf").value;
        var csrfName = document.getElementById("csrf").getAttribute("name");
         $.ajax({
                 url: $(this).attr("action"),
                 context: document.body,
                 type: 'post',
                 dataType: "json",
                 data:$(this).serialize(),
                 beforeSend: function( xhr ) {    
                     xhr.setRequestHeader(csrfName, csrf);  
                 }
             }).done(function(res) {
                 alert("hi");
                 alert(res);
                 alert(res.viewBean);
                 $('#myTable').dataTable({

                         "aaData":res.viewBean,
                         "aocolumndefs":[{ "mData": "userId" },
                                      { "mData": "action" },
                                      { "mData": "airlineCode" },
                                      { "mData": "companyName" },
                                      { "mData": "requestedDate"},
                                      { "mData": "profile"},
                                      { "mData": "mrtUser"}],  
                        "bDestroy":true
                 }); 
             }).fail(function(data){
                 $("#result").html("<span>Error</span>");
             });
         return false;
     });
 });
```

Please tell me the mistake that i have done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your initialization

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
    "aaData":res.viewBean,
    "aocolumndefs":[{ "mData": "userId" },
         { "mData": "action" },
         { "mData": "airlineCode" },
         { "mData": "companyName" },
         { "mData": "requestedDate"},
         { "mData": "profile"},
         { "mData": "mrtUser"}],  
          "bDestroy":true,
    retrieve: true, //// Add this line
});
```

DataTables does not allow initialisation options to be altered at any time other than at initialisation time. Any manipulation of the table after initialisation must be done through the API and trying to set the initialisation options once the table has already been initialised will result in the error.

Form More info http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Comment: $('#myTable').dataTable({
                   "aaData":res.viewBean,
                   "aoColumns":[{"sTitle" : "Airline Code",  
                                  "mData" : "airlineCode" }],
                 retrieve: true,  I have modified the column values like this and yet not getting displayed